# Redirecting (301) multiple urls with the same query string using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wonder if anyone can help. I've researched this issue but not found a post that QUITE matches it so I'm a bit lost as to how to proceed.

I have a whole bunch of URLs from an old site that each use the same query string, which is used to redirect users to the mobile version of the pages. I would like to redirect these URLs to pages on the new site so that the new URLs don't display the query string.

So:
www.old-site.com/first-page/?type=88 should redirect to www.new-site.com/first-page;
www.old-site.com/second-page/?type=88 should redirect to www.new-site.com/second-page; and
www.old-site.com/third-page/?type=88 should redirect to www.new-site.com/third-page, etc.

I've tracked down code that will redirect one URL with a query string to another URL without a query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=88
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new-site.com? [R=301,L,NC]
```

but, I am not sure how to deal with all these different pages that use the same query string, but each need to end up at different destinations.

Any help that anyone can provide would be most helpful.

With kind regards,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=88
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new-site.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @starkeen that was it exactly! Thanks for your quick work on this one. It's good to know I was nearly there.